# Permisos sobre algunas columnas de una tabla (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

¿Existe alguna manera de limitar lo que un usuario pueda realizar algunas acciones ya sea ***INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, etc.*** En columnas especificas de una tabla?

Ya se que puedo ***limitar permisos sobres usuarios***, pero lo que busco es limitar ese usuario a algunas columnas no a todas.

***Para dar todos los privilegios a un usuario sobre todas la base de datos uso :***

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'pepito'@'localhost';
```

***Si lo quiero limitar a la base de datos empresa :***

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON empresa.* TO 'pepito'@'localhost';
```

***Si lo quiero limitar a la base de datos empresas y tabla a empleados :***

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON empresa.empleados TO 'pepito'@'localhost';
```

***Luego se aplica con :***

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Y solucionado, ***pero lo que yo quiero*** es ***limitar esas columnas de empleados*** por motivos de seguridad

***Por ejemplo :*** Tengo la siguiente información.

- ***Base de datos :*** empresa
- ***Tabla :*** empleados
- ***Columnas :*** dni,nombre,ap1,ap2,sueldo,fechaNac.
- ***Usuario :*** Pepito
- ***Host :*** Localhost

***Nota :*** Esos datos son inventados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Existe 2 niveles en MySQL.

##### El prime nivel se trata sobre permisos de usuarios.

##### Segundo nivel se trata de db.

En ese segundo nivel puedes decidir que tabla se puede modificar de una base de datos e incluso que columnas de dichas tablas. Se puede ver esto permiso con :

```
SELECT USER,HOST.SELECT_PRIV,UPDATE_PRIV FROM MYSQL.USER;
```

Te mostrara el usuario con donde se conecta y si puede hacer ***UPDATE y SELECT*** sobre esa tabla.

***Por ejemplo :*** Quieres dar permisos de ***SELECT*** sobre los campo de una tabla pues seria algo similar a esto :

```
GRANT SELECT(COLUMNA1,COLUMNA3) ON TuBaseDato.TuTabla TO 'TuUSuario'@'TuHost';
```

Imagínate que tienes la ***base de datos empresa*** con ***la tabla empleados*** cuyas ***columnas son : dni,nombre,ap1,ap2,sueldo,fechaNac.***

Y solo queremos que el ***usuario pepito*** ***conectado desde localhost*** solo pueda ***ver el nombre y el ap1,*** por motivos de seguridad, pues se haría de la siguiente forma.

```
GRANT SELECT(nombre,ap1) ON empresa.empleados TO 'pepito'@'localhost';
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]